How to sign flutter app with new keystore file
I Lost my old keystore and now i created a new one. When trying to sign the app with the new key, i get an error saying "keystore was tampered with, or password was incorrect". The password is correct.
How can I sign the app with the new key without getting the error
Useless details if you wanna know how i got here:
Old laptop no longer working, got a new one and cloned the repo from my github. The key was long ago saved to mediafire and so i downloaded it and tried signing the app with it and got the same error, hence i decided to create a new key and now Im still getting the same error with the new key.

You can refer to this: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/thread/204649975/i-lost-my-old-keystore-how-can-i-release-a-new-version-of-app?hl=en

If you forgot the kesystore password or lost your keystore file, you can request for keystore reset by link below.
https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/contact/key?hl=en
Once you request for keystore reset you will receive an email from googleplay-developer-support and instruct you what to do next.
After that you will be able to update your application in google play console.
